# Are "flaps under the wind" and "flaps in the wind" both correct?

Tags: meaning

I am not sure, but I think they broadly mean the same thing. However, I don't see a lot of entries on Google for "flaps under the wind" as in "the flag flapped under the wind". Are both grammatically correct or not and why?

For example:

> The flag flapped violently under the wind.
>
> The flag flapped violently in the wind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The flag flapped violently **in** the wind.

This is certainly grammatical and idiomatic.

> The flag flapped violently **under** the wind.

While this *is* grammatical, it doesn't sound entirely right. As it stands, it has a strange interpretation of the flag being spatially *underneath* an air current that disturbs the air *above* it. But, if that were the case, then the flag wouldn't be flapping violently.

I would say that this sense could be corrected by adding a word to the end of the sentence. Something like:

> The flag flapped violently **under** the wind's ***influence***.

This changes the sense of *under* from being one of spatial location to one of control.

It's possible, of course, to understand the intended meaning without the additional context. But I think it would be prudent to make the addition if *under* is used.